# how can I sync Date time in two computers?

Tags: unix

I have two computers, but I can´t change the time in one, so I have to sync one of this, with the other one. It has QNX. What can I do?? only commands

Comment: how about using ntp?

Comment: @MaQleod the OP does not have `root` access to both machines so that is not an option. That's what I understood by "I can´t change the time in one".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution would be to install [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) on both machines and have them sync to the same server. This is not an option, of course, if you only have `root` access to one of the two.

Assuming that you have ssh access to both machines, that `machine1` is the one whose date you *cannot* change and `machine2` the one whose date you *can* change (as the `root` user), you can do something like this:

```
remote_time=`ssh user@machine1 date` && date -s "$remote_time"
```

You will need to change `user` to your user name on `machine1`. If you run this command when logged in as `root` on `machine2`, you will set its date to the same value as `machine1`.

EXPLANATION:

The command above will `ssh` as the user `user` to `machine1` and save the result of `date` (the current time and date for `machine1`) into the variable `$remote_time`. If the `ssh` exits successfully (`&&`), the second part of the command will set the time of `machine2` (the machine the command was run from) to the value of `$remote_time`.

CAVEAT: The two commands take some time to complete. When I tested them on my machine, they took 0.3 seconds, it could take more on yours. Just be aware that if you need millisecond accuracy, this will not work. Then again, if you need millisecond accuracy, the *only* thing that will work is syncing both machines to an NTP server.

Comment: Would it not be safer to use UTC (-u option of date command)? During the DST window, the time could ambiguous.  OK, after thinking, at least for CET, the string indicates if DST is in effect or not).

Comment: On my system (CentOS 5.4) I have to use quotes, like this : date -s "$remote_time"

Comment: Whoops, yes absolutely. And even if it weren't required here, which it is as you point out, one should still [always quote variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/22222). Fixed now, thanks, @DavidBalažic!

Answer (score 1):

If you need more accuracy and don't want to use ntp for whatever reason, you can use this modification over the @terdon method.

Lazy method. Suppose that you spend 0.85s in the ssh connection:

```
host1# b=`date +%s.%N`; a=`echo $b + 0.85|bc`;  ssh -4 -C user@host2 "date --set=\"@$a\""
```

More sophisticated:

```
host1# a=`ssh user@host2 date +%s.%N` ; b=`ssh user@host2 date +%s.%N`; c=`echo $b +$b -$a | bc ` ; echo $c ;ssh user@host2 "date --set=\"@$c\" --rfc-3339=ns" ;date --rfc-3339=ns


1514483228.883729365
2017-12-28 18:47:08.883729365+01:00
2017-12-28 18:47:08.790489767+01:00
```

As prerequisite you need to have client and server prepared to exchange user keys to avoid password inputs and be sure that you have reverse dns resolution of both host1 machine or you will have a laggy ssh connection.